# Filtering Looker Studio Dashboard Embedded in Website by User Login

Tags: google-cloud-platform, looker-studio

I have created a dashboard in Google Looker Studio to visualize student marks from a dummy dataset. My website requires individual user authentication (username and password) for students to log in. I want to embed the Looker Studio dashboard into my website, but I need to filter the displayed data so that each student only sees their own information.

Is it possible to pass a username or other user identifier as a parameter to the embedded Looker Studio dashboard code in order to dynamically filter the visualization or data for each individual user? If so, how can this be achieved?

Any help or guidance on how to implement this functionality within Looker Studio would be greatly appreciated. I am new to Looker Studio and would like to understand the best approach for achieving this user-specific filtering. Thank you in advance for your assistance.

[The current Dashboard looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssxAV.png)

[I'm expecting Dashboard to look like this to logged in student](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veUgV.png)

Comment: look into [filter by email](https://www.optimizesmart.com/how-to-filter-by-email-in-google-data-studio/) setting

Comment: thank you @rockinfreakshow, but the thing is student just don't use gmail email id's, is there way if students are using some other email id such as outlook.

Comment: this feature requires user signed in to a google account be it with gmail OR lets say [outlook linked google account](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/27441#existingemail)